# reledmac table and edindex

Tags: reledmac

When I try to set the table offered in the manual of reledmac, I get the error: "undefined control sequence \reserved\c -> l@d@index", which definetly is a problem of the \edindex. Normal \index works. What am I doing wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
 \pstart
 \begin{edtabularl}
 \textbf{\Large I} & wish I was a little bug\edindex{bug} &
 \textbf{\Large I} & eat my peas with honey\index{honey} \\
  & With whiskers \edtext{round}{\Afootnote{around}} my tummy &
  & I've done it all my life. \\
  & I'd climb into a honey\index{honey} pot &
  & It makes the peas taste funny \\
  & And get my tummy gummy.\index{gummy} &
  & But it keeps them on the knife.
 \end{edtabularl}
 \pend

 \endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it is a bug of reledmac. Please open a github issue (but I can't tell you when I would have time to solve it)

Comment: Just did: https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was, indeed, a bug on reledmac when using `\edindex` in `\edtabular` environments.

The version 2.15.1, just send on CTAN, would fix that. We should keept the first answer, as it show typical mistake with indexing in reledmac.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a bug in \edindex, as I have thought in a first quick reading.

You have written in your preamble

```
makeindex[name=test]
```

that means you should use `\index[test]{the-word-for-index}` or `\edindex[test]{the-word-for-index}`. If you don't want to use the optional argument, as you have only one index, just write in your preamble

```
makeindex
```

Without name argument.

Indeed, there is a little bug with `\edindex`: it should not produce ununderstandable error, but ignore the entry and write a warning message, as `\index` do. So I let the issue opened, but it is on a low priority.

As explained in the handbook, you also must use call `\makeindex` AFTER loading reledmac. But there is still, and really, a bug with tabularl.

Comment: That is not really true. Except for the error it writes „[test]“ into the text, I'm afraid. Or, if I change it to no index-name it writes the file-name.

Comment: I have written a too short form of the command syntax. Now it should be clearer.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the order of makeindex corrected. As you stated yourself, it is still a bug.