# reledmac edtable and alignment

Tags: tables, reledmac

After todays speedy fix of a bug in reledmac (vid.  [reledmac table and edindex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327684/reledmac-table-and-edindex) )
I try to include the table into my code so that it's not distinct from normal text except for the columns. The edtable feature is very basic and the table is always centered. I thought I could just include a third column with \hfill so that the whole table is aligned to the left. Unfortunately this messes up the alignment of column 2.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart\noindent
O HYMEN! O hymenee!
Why do you tantalize me thus?
O why sting me for a swift moment only?
Why can you not continue? O why do you now cease?
Is it because, if you continued beyond the swift moment, you would
soon certainly kill me? \pend
\pstart{}\begin{edtabularl}
O CAPTAIN! & my Captain! our fearful trip is done;  & \hfill \\
& The ship has weather'd every rack, the prize we sought is won;  & \hfill \\
& The port is near, the bells I hear, the people all exulting,  & \hfill \\
& While follow eyes the steady keel, the vessel grim and daring:  & \hfill \\
& But O heart! heart! heart!  & \hfill \\
& O the bleeding drops of red,  & \hfill \\
& Where on the deck my Captain lies, & \hfill \\
& Fallen cold and dead. & \hfill 
 \end{edtabularl}\pend{}\endnumbering
 \end{document}
```

This is a screen shot of column 2:

[image: The alignment of column 2]

Is it too much of a hack?

Comment: hum, sorry, don't know. the edtabular is not a very used feature of reledmac.

Comment: hmm, it's a pity. because it's lo-fi character makes it perfect for tweaking some text-placement. but if it's more an experimental feature, i completely understand!

Comment: you could open an issue, but it's a complex feature, and I have many, many opened issue. Maybe some one will foud here a solution

Comment: I don't annoy you with another feature-request! I noticed that the problem exists even without the \hfill. column 2 is uneven. I will return to longtable and work something out with \vspace*{-\baselineskip} before and after the table to get rid of the space. Apart from that it more or less works in reledmac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a little late, but this code works and doesn't mess up the alignment.

I used the \hfill directly in the cell and remove the space before the column seperator.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
O HYMEN! O hymenee!
Why do you tantalize me thus?
O why sting me for a swift moment only?
Why can you not continue? O why do you now cease?
Is it because, if you continued beyond the swift moment, you would
soon certainly kill me?

\noindent\begin{edtabularl}
O CAPTAIN! &my Captain! our fearful trip is done;\hfill\\
&The ship has weather'd every rack, the prize we sought is won;\hfill\\
&The port is near, the bells I hear, the people all exulting,\hfill\\
&While follow eyes the steady keel, the vessel grim and daring:\hfill\\
&But O heart! heart! heart!\hfill\\
&O the bleeding drops of red,\hfill\\
&Where on the deck my Captain lies,\hfill\\
&Fallen cold and dead.\hfill
\end{edtabularl}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```